# IOS: button glare

Tags: ios, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

I see in some apps that when I press a button compare a glare over it, what's the way to obtain this result?
I noticed that it is implemented on the bar button, but is it possible on normal UIButton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be referring to the following property of the `UIButton` :

`[button setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES]`